# Web player play DCE file

Tags: javascript, php, video-streaming

Is there any web player which play  .DCE(Drive Cam Video Event File). I have tried with JW player,Video js etc, none of them support. I would like to play .DCE file in web and am looking for some good web players which support .DCE

Comment: http://file.downloadatoz.com/dce-file-extension/dce-player.html

Comment: Thank you, but these players support in windows,mac etc. I would like to integrate this in website.

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/embed-vlc-player-html